# Issues with selenium in Python (Maybe installing chrome webdriver)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I think I've installed chrome web driver correctly although it may be the issue, but when i run command prompt and type "chromedriver" it runs, but when i go into sublime and just try to go to google and print the title and URL to verify that things are working i get this error

I am not really sure what it means or what it is trying to say to me

**The code I'm running**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
```

**The Error I'm getting**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 900, in _find_spec
AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\python\selenium testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 902, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 879, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 449, in spec_from_loader
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 212, in is_package
    return hasattr(self.__get_module(fullname), "__path__")
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 116, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\Coding\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\python\email.py", line 8, in <module>
    loop (
NameError: name 'loop' is not defined
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: It looks like you have a file `email.py`. Try to rename it and see if it works

Comment: That worked, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had little time yesterday;I will quickly write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem you are having is the following:

- You import `webdriver`
- The import triggers the import of `email.parser` as we see in the error

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
```

- the python interpreter looks in its path for a module called `email`.
- It found a module, but its not the one it was looking for, but your very own module, as we see in the error

```
File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\python\email.py", line 8, in <module>
    loop (
```

- As we can see, the module was found at `C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\python\email.py` and, as I suspected, this is not the path of the actual module the interpreter was searching for.